# Transferring data from a serial Port to a text file

Tags: c, file, serial-port, scanf

I'm using debian and I have to transfer data from a serial port into a text file to then get read into a database. I think how im setting the port up is wrong, and I keep stumbling across so many different examples, My current code (below) keeps giving me 3 warnings, "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" I think it has to do with the values that are being returned, I did some reading on what pointers return, but it wasn't too clear to me, I was wondering if someone could give some insight on the issue, or if there are any glaringly obvious issues that I am missing. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

```
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <fcntl.h>
       #include <sys/stat.h>
       #include <termios.h>
       #include <string.h>

        #define BAUDRATE B115200
        #define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyS0"
        main()
        {

         int n;

         FILE *file;
         file = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR, O_NOCTTY);

         if(file == NULL){
                printf("initiation error. \n");
                return 1;
           }

       FILE *fp;
          fp = open("testfile.txt", O_RDWR);

            while(1){

                      file = scanf("%d", &n);
                      fprintf(fp, "%d", n);
                       fclose(fp);
                       }
         fclose(file);
   }
```

so what i think this does, or what i intend it to do at least is set file to read data from the port, and then store those values in n, which then get printed in a text file.

Comment: Study [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html) for configuring the serial port and reading data from it.  Currently your code does neither.  Spend time up front to get it right, instead of wasting twice as much time later trying to figure what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
   FILE *fp;
   fp = open("testfile.txt", O_RDWR);
```

is wrong, you meant `fopen()` on the last line, don't confuse raw I/O with the C runtime library's buffered functions.

This is also one reason for your error, since the file descriptor (not a pointer) returned by `open()` is an integer (see the [`open()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) manual page and compare that to [`fopen()`'s](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)).

**UPDATE**: I also fail to understand what you're trying to do with the `scanf()` line.

If you want to read an integer from a `FILE *`, you should use `fscanf()`. The return value is the number of successful conversions, which is used in error-checking:

```
if(fscanf(file, "%d", &n) == 1)
  fprintf(fp, "%d", n);
```

That will read an integer from the serial port `file`, and if successful print it out to the output file `fp`.

Comment: okay thank you, that did work, it seemed O_RDWR and fopen did not agree, by switching it to just "a" took care of one of the warnings

Comment: @user3681077 Of course the arguments are different, please *read* the documentation for the functions. You seem to be programming in the blind by just guessing.

Comment: file = scanf("%d", &n);

Comment: I know the warning will go away if I just say, scanf("%d" ,&n);                expect I need the contents of file stored in n. I know that fscanf is redirectable, this brings up a whole lot more issues